# How to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^p (y_i-x_i)^2$ with constraints $\sum_{i=1}^p y_i - 1 =0$ and $\forall i=\overline{1,p}:-y_i \le 0$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_p) \in \mathbb R^p$. I'm solving the constrained optimization problem

> $$\begin{align*}
> \text{min} &\quad \sum_{i=1}^p (y_i-x_i)^2 \\
> \text{s.t} &\quad \sum_{i=1}^p y_i - 1 &&=0\\
>            &\quad\forall  i = \overline{1,p}: -y_i &&\le 0 
> \end{align*}$$

**My attempt:**

Let $f(y) = \sum_{i=1}^p (y_i-x_i)^2$, $h(y) = \sum_{i=1}^p y_i - 1$, and $g_i(y) = -y_i$ for all $i = \overline{1,p}$.

We have $f,g_i$ are convex and $h$ is linear. Let $\alpha =(1/p, \cdots, 1/p)$. Then $h(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha) <0$ for all $i = \overline{1,p}$. It follows that Slater's condition is satisfied. By Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, we have $$\begin{aligned} \begin{cases}
\forall i = \overline{1,p}:\mu_i &\ge 0 \\
\forall i = \overline{1,p}: g_i(y) &\le 0\\
h(y) &=0 \\
\forall i = \overline{1,p}:\mu_i g_i(y)&=0 \\
\nabla f (y)+ \lambda\nabla h (y)+ \mu_i \nabla g_i (y) &=0
\end{cases}
&\iff \begin{cases}
\forall i = \overline{1,p}:\mu_i &\ge 0 \\
\forall i = \overline{1,p}:-y_i &\le 0\\
\sum_{i=1}^p y_i - 1&=0 \\
\forall i = \overline{1,p}: -\mu_i y_i &=0 \\
\forall i = \overline{1,p}: 2(y_i - x_i) +\lambda - \mu_i &= 0
\end{cases} \\ \end{aligned}$$

Then I'm stuck at solving the last system of equations.

How can I proceed to solve it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| y - x \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & y \succeq 0 \\
& \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} y = 1
\end{alignat*}
$$

Then it is the exact problem as in [Orthogonal Projection onto the Unit Simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402504).

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning behind *the trick is to leave non negativity constrain implicit*? I'm unable to see how my KKT conditions is compatible/consistent with your solution.

Comment: I wanted to have a single parameter to apply the Newton Iteration on. Newton iteration is for unconstrained optimization so if I had $ \lambda $ it wouldn't fit for its non negativity.

Comment: I incorporated your ideas into my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563410/projection-on-probability-simplex-with-kkt-method). If you are interested, please have a look at it :)

Comment: Why would you open so many questions which are the same?