# Projection of a Gaussian random vector onto the unit $\ell_1$ ball

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, convex-geometry, projection, geometric-probability

Let $Z_n  \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Z_n \sim N(0, I_n)$ be a gaussian random vector, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix. The unit ball is defined as

$$ L_1 = \left[X \in \mathbb{R}^n: \| X \|_1 \leq 1 \right]$$

The orthogonal projection onto $L_1$ is

$$ P_{L_1}(Z_n) = \underset{\mathbf{x} \in L_1}{\operatorname{argmin}} \| \mathbf{x} - Z_n \|_2 $$

I need to find a nontrivial (as a function of the dimension $n$) *lower  bound* for

$$ \mathbb{P} \left(  \max_{i \in (1,\dots,n)} [P_{L_1}(Z_n)]_i = 0 \right), $$

where $ [P_{L_1}(Z_n)]i $ is the $i$-th  coordinate of $P_{L_1}(Z_n)$. Does anyone have an idea (or references) on how to solve this problem? In particular, is there a general expression for that (or integral form)?

Comment: Why are some vectors lowercase and bold and others uppercase and non-bold?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327504/339790)